# Add string in parameter without commas in Oracle PlSql

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql, parameters

I'm trying to replace a variable values with a string of string, but i need to separate these strings with a comma.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM RUOLI WHERE 1=1 AND ID IN ('RuoloASL1','Prova') ORDER BY DESCRIZIONE
```

and it works good, but if i want to pass these values through a parameter like this

```
SELECT * FROM RUOLI WHERE 1=1 AND ID IN (:RESULT) ORDER BY DESCRIZIONE
```

it not works, because in RESULT replace this 'RuoloASL1,Prova'.

I need to get 'RuoloASL1','Prova' with a single parameter.. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match against a csv string, you can use `like`:

```
where ',' || :result || ',' like ',%' || id  || ',%'
```

Or a regex:

```
where regexp_like(result, '^|,' || id || ',|$')
```

But overall it would be better to pass as many parameters as there are values to match. This will be much more efficient than using strings or regex functions.